# Find all $x$ numbers for $(x-1)(x-3) > 0$

Tags: calculus

I am learning calculus from [Calculus by Michael Spivak](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0914098918) and the exercise is to find all x numbers for $(x-1)(x-3) > 0$. Steps below are my procedure.

1. $(x-1)(x-3) > 0$
2. $x^2-4x+3 > 0$
3. $x^2 > 4x-3$
4. $x > +-\sqrt{4x-3}$

I was wondering if I can say that $x > +-\sqrt{4x-3}$ is the answer.

Comment: When is a product of two numbers positive? When both are positive or both negative.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't solved the inequality. You are looking for real valued solutions for $x$: values of $x$ that satisfy the inequality.

Keep the inequality in factored form.

$(x-1)(x-3) \gt 0$ is positive $(1)$ if both factors are positive, or $(2)$ if both factors are negative.

1. when $(x-1)> 0$ and $(x - 3)>0 \implies x \gt 3.$
2. when $(x - 1) < 0$ and $(x-3)\lt 0 \implies x \lt 1.$

So the inequality holds if $$x \in (-\infty, 1) \cup (3, \infty)$$

When $x \in [1, 3]$, the inequality fails.

Comment: Is it possible to use this technique to find $x$ for $x^2-2x+2>0$? or I need to use graph for that one?

Comment: That inequality is always true.

Answer (score 3):

Nope. You can't. Your solution $x > \sqrt {4x-3}$ does not convey anything. The question wants the set of real numbers for which this relation is valid.

Draw a number line and use this hint : Product of two positives or two negatives is positive and product of a positive and negative is negative!